# JSON does not display some UTF-8 characters corectly

Tags: mysql, json, symfony, encoding, utf-8

I have a table in mysql db. I have no control over that tables content. The column I'm retrieving is encoded into UTF-8_danish_ci. Data consists of string that have norwegian charackters: `å ø æ`. Data looks correct when accessing trough mysql CLI. In symfony2 project when I retrieve data with doctrine ORM and try to `json_encode()` I get error that some part of the array I'm sending to encode is not UTF-8.

I've even made a helper method to make sure all results are converted to UTF-8 before sent to encode. In this case json works, but shows `?` instead `å ø æ` chars.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the data okay after you retrieve from the mysql driver and before you encode into JSON?

Comment: Not quite, instead `å ø æ` I get some black rhomboids.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back, had to run out of town.  Added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For some very odd reason. When displaying JSON string it shows those escaped chars. When I loaded json string into jquery plugin for autocomplete it parsed these escaped chars correctly. I do have charset: utf8 in my yml config file. Cant really say why as raw json escapes chars and on html page shows them correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an issue with the driver retrieving data from MySQL.  Make sure that charset is part of you connections definition:

`doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname:   database
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  utf8`

This will cause Doctrine to connect via "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", explicitly requesting utf8.  (BTW, check your PDO version.. PDO prior to 5.3.6 didn't support charset= for some reason; Doctrine used a "SET NAMES " hack executed before every query to try to workaround this.  If you're using an older version of PDO this might be a problem in recent versions of Symfony.)

If it's not the database driver, then you might have doubly encoded strings and/or strings with mixed encodings. Take a look at the [forceutf8](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8) library.